# Springboot application not recognizing any @RestController or @Service, and i think the @Repository too

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security

I have springboot application which i was working on, on a different computer, i cloned the project from github and set up my intellij, installed all dependencies and tried to run the program.

The first thing i notice is that the security configuration is bypassed. A password is generated for me despite me having a Config file in place. When i open localhost:8080 and login, all endpoints dont work either.

All of these worked on my previous computer on the same version of intellij.

- I have tried Using @ComponentScan but I still get the same result.
- I have added this line to my application.properties `logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE` and it only shows that one endpoint is avalible, "/error"

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appholdings</groupId>
    <artifactId>appname</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>appname</name>
    <description>appname</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.429</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Security Config

```
package com.mootoholdings.ecommserver.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/products/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/categories", "/api/categories/*").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
//                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
        // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
        // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
        // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Authentication Filter

```
import com.mootoholdings.ecommserver.service.JWTService;

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JWTService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);

        userEmail = jwtService.decodeUsername(jwt);

        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
         try {
            // something may throw an exception
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
         } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
             log.error(e.getMessage());
         }
    }

}
```

my Application entry point

```
package com.mootoholdings.ecommserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EcommserverApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EcommserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

jwt service

```
package com.mootoholdings.ecommserver.service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class JWTService {
    private final SupplierRepository supplierRepository;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RiderRepository riderRepository;
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;
    private final DistributorRepository distributorRepository;

    public JWTService(UserRepository userRepository,
                      RiderRepository riderRepository,
                      AdminRepository adminRepository,
                      DistributorRepository distributorRepository,
                      SupplierRepository supplierRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.riderRepository = riderRepository;
        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
        this.distributorRepository = distributorRepository;

        this.supplierRepository = supplierRepository;
    }

    @Value("${SECRET_KEY}")
    private String SECRET_KEY;

    // Extracts Username
    public String decodeUsername(String token){
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public String decodeUserId(String token){
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getId);
    }

    public String extractFirstRole(String token) {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> rolesClaim = extractClaim(token, claims ->
                ((List<?>) claims.get("roles")).stream()
                        .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.toString()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
        if (!rolesClaim.isEmpty()) {
            String roleString = rolesClaim.get(0).getAuthority().split("=")[1];
            return roleString.substring(0, roleString.length() - 1);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    // Extract claims from token
    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver){
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    // Makes new token
    public String genToken(UserDetails userDetails, String role){
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails, role);
    }

    // Makes new token
    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails,
            String role
    ){
        if (Objects.equals(role, "DISTRIBUTOR")){
            log.info("In distributor");
            Distributor distributor = distributorRepository.findDistributorByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
            return getJwt(extraClaims, userDetails, distributor.getId(), distributor.getFirstName(), distributor.getLastName());
        }
        else if (Objects.equals(role, "SUPPLIER")){
            log.info("In supplier");
            Supplier supplier = supplierRepository.findSupplierByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
            log.info("attempting get JWT");
            return getJwt(extraClaims, userDetails, supplier.getId(), supplier.getFirstName(), supplier.getLastName());
        }
        else if (Objects.equals(role, "RIDER")){
            log.info("In rider");
            Rider rider = riderRepository.findRiderByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
            log.info("attempting get JWT");
            return getJwt(extraClaims, userDetails, rider.getId(), rider.getFirstName(), rider.getLastName());
        }
        else if (Objects.equals(role, "ADMIN")){
            log.info("In admin");
            Admin admin = adminRepository.findAdminByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
            return getJwt(extraClaims, userDetails, admin.getId(), admin.getFirstName(), admin.getLastName());
        }
        else {
            log.info("In User");
            User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
            return getJwt(extraClaims, userDetails, user.getId(), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName());
        }


    }

    private String getJwt(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails, long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .claim ("id", id)
                .claim("firstName", firstName)
                .claim("lastName", lastName)
                .claim("roles", userDetails.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    // Validate token
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails){
        final String username = decodeUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token){
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token){
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims (String token){
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecommdb?sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
 spring.datasource.username=user
 spring.datasource.password=user
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
```

Application Config

```
package com.mootoholdings.ecommserver.config;


@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;
    private final RiderRepository riderRepository;
    private final DistributorRepository distributorRepository;
    private final SupplierRepository supplierRepository;

    public ApplicationConfig(UserRepository userRepository, AdminRepository adminRepository,
            RiderRepository riderRepository, DistributorRepository distributorRepository,
            SupplierRepository supplierRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
        this.riderRepository = riderRepository;
        this.distributorRepository = distributorRepository;
        this.supplierRepository = supplierRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            Optional<Rider> rider = riderRepository.findByEmail(username);
            if (rider.isPresent()) {
                log.info("authenticating rider");
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(rider.get().getEmail(),
                        rider.get().getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
            if (user.isPresent()) {
                log.info("authenticating user");
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.get().getEmail(),
                        user.get().getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            Optional<Admin> admin = adminRepository.findByEmail(username);
            if (admin.isPresent()) {
                log.info("authenticating admin");
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(admin.get().getEmail(),
                        admin.get().getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            Optional<Distributor> distributor = distributorRepository.findByEmail(username);
            if (distributor.isPresent()) {
                log.info("authenticating dist");
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(distributor.get().getEmail(),
                        distributor.get().getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            Optional<Supplier> supplier = supplierRepository.findByEmail(username);
            if (supplier.isPresent()) {
                log.info("authenticating supplier");
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(supplier.get().getEmail(),
                        supplier.get().getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

folder structure
[image: FolderStructure]

What could i be doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: Included package names.
**UPDATE**: Run it on github codespaces and its working, so i guess its something to do with my machines setup

Comment: For starters stop mixing versions (you are mixing 3.0.3 and 3.0.6) and introducing random dependencies (spring-jdbc with a version). Please include the packages of the classes you posted (or at least make sure they are under `com.mootoholdings.ecommserver` else they won't get detected.

Comment: can you please add code for class **JWTService.java**

Comment: @M.Deinum added an image for folder structure and package names.

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian jwt service included

Comment: What is in the config package? Which Java version is in use, how are you running things? The `maven-compiler-plugin` isn't really needed as Spring Boot already configures that properly.

Comment: @M.Deinum it has three main things, the Application Config, Jwt Filter and the Security Config. My hunch is that it has nothing to do with the configs because this code if pushed is working just fine on elastic beanstalk, and it worked before on my previous laptop. However i feel it could have something to do with the dependencies. The Java version is 17

Comment: Then run it on the other machines. The fact that it runs on other machines doesn't say that much, different OS, different Java version, different environment variables etc. etc. all influence things. As stated don't mix version of a framework (you do) as that is trouble waiting to happen (which means youa re trying to outsmart the Spring Boot dependency management and config). Finally I asked the question how are you running things, this is something you haven't answered.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean by how am i running things? With the play button in intellij. Previous machine was windows, worked on that machine, current is windows, not working. Same OS, same Java Version, same Environment Variables. One works one doesnt.

Comment: That at least answers how you are running things. if you state they are the same do a compare between the systems. There must be something different could even be your run configuration (same intellij versions/editions?)

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE for us to answer your question if it is your machine setup since none of us can reproduce your setup, and you have not provided enough information for anyone of us to replicate your problem. We cant spend hours asking you ”have you done this, have you done that, etc etc”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a complete debug and it boils down to the Laptop name. The original name has a space in it and so when it starts to search for repositories within the project it fails and cancels the search. To fix this i just created another account and moved the project to the Public folder cause im unable to change the laptop name, now everything works just fine.